# Memeo Instant Backup from external drive to local drive

Tags: windows-7, backup, external-hard-drive

I just got a Seagate GoFlex external drive and would like to do something which is the opposite of what most people do: I'd like to do periodic backups *from* the external drive *to* the local drive. The reason is that the external drive is the primary storage for a bunch of computers and I need a backup from the external drive. And there is a computer on the network which could serve as the backup. So I need the direction of the backup to be *from* external *to* local.

Is it possible with Memeo Instant Backup? (This is the software that came bundled with the Seagate drive.) So far it looks like it can only handle *from* local drive *to* external drive, but maybe someone knows how to reverse the direction.

Comment: I would recommend using another backup software. The memeo that comes with the GoFlex is crap. You are also likely to have licensing issues, it is a known bug. Memeo thinks it is a trial version even though you bought it. There are many free and better backup programs around.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Any specific programs you have in mind? As a requirement let me add that I'd like to be able to backup automatically on a daily basis.